# how to get actual price of a product in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, order-email, special-price

How to add actual price in order email template?

I am using this code `$_actualPrice = $_product->getPrice();`

Comment: i am using $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getProdcut()->getFinalPrice()) ;

Comment: i have used getPrice() and also getFinalPrice() but printing  same price

Comment: Can you try to load product by id then try getFinalPrice().

Comment: `order email template` mean?

Comment: i am using this code but its showing for all product not for specific sku  <?php
$product_sku = TEST_PRO_11; // use your own sku number
if ($product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku( $product_sku )){
    echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(25, true);
 }
 else {
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ;
}

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i  am getting product by id ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$_taxHelper = $this->helper('tax');
$_store = $_product->getStore();
$_convertedFinalPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()));
$_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice);
```

EDIT:
I just use these code on my product view.phtml to show the actual price.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_taxHelper = $this->helper('tax');
$_store = $_product->getStore();
$_convertedFinalPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()));
$_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice);
```

Comment: i used your code but its .....Call to a member function getStore()

Comment: can you put some code?
e.g. where do your "$_product" come from?
is it $_product = $this->getProduct();?

Comment: now its error Call to a member function roundPrice(). i am using it on order email template can you send me full code

Comment: i am using it order email template app/design/base/default/template/email/order/item/default.phtml